# how to find print data for if same class name is available for the entire table

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello guys am trying to print and write the user reviews into an excel sheet but am having trouble in printing and writing data into an excel sheet using selenium web driver as it is returning a null pointer exception.

am using seleniumg 2.4.1 with jdk 1.7

this is the code that am using.

```
    public void f() throws IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {


      FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Desktop\\eclipse\\Test Results\\Android_Results.xls");
      WritableWorkbook wb=Workbook.createWorkbook(fo);
      WritableSheet ws=wb.createSheet("LoginResults", 0);


      driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("simsons tapedout");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbqfb']")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.className("preview-overlay-container")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='body-content']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]")).click();

      str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]")).getText();
      String s[] = str.split("\n");
      System.out.println(s.length);
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(s[i]);
          {
              Label label = new Label(0,i,s[i]);
              ws.addCell(label);
              }
              wb.write();
              wb.close();
          }

  }
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("https://play.google.com/");

  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
  }

}
```

am unable to figure out were am i going wrong. a little advice would be great

Thanks in advance

Comment: stack trace? where exception occured?

Comment: the exception occurs up when i try to write it in excelsheet

Comment: And what is the error or exception? I asked for stacktrace... :)

Comment: Null pointer Exception...